# verify which github account my terminal is using

Tags: github, terminal, osx-mavericks

How do I verify which github credentials my terminal is using for pushing,etc? I have multiple github accounts and multiple computers. The present situation is for a mac osx mavericks.

In my particular case, my accounts are collaborators on each other's project. To keep things simple, imagine I only have two accounts and two computers. I want to know which github credential computer Z is using. Another, perhaps cheaper, way of looking at this is: if I cd into a particular repo, how can I tell if the present account is a collaborator or the owner of the repo?

Answer (score 0):

From the directory you created to hold the data from github type:

```
git remote -v
```

This will detail the repo and the URL

Comment: actually this does not. All it does is print the name of the repo. Let me update my question to say credential instead of account. Maybe the error is mine.

Comment: In that case try: "git log"

Answer (score 0):

From your repo directory run

```
git config -l
```

I'm not sure if grep is installed on OSX by default, but if it is you can probably go a bit further and do this

```
git config -l | grep user
```

Comment: This works on one computer and not on another. Both osx mavericks. But it's probably the best answer I am going to get. On the computer that owns the repo, it works. On the computer that is a collaborator on the repo it does not work. Which means I still don't know which account that computer is using to access the repo. I know I can do a commit and check from there, but that is not an acceptable approach.

Comment: That is very odd, it may be worthwhile to open the global and the local git config files on that computer and have a look inside. Local config is located in the repo: **.git/config** Global config is located in your home directory and is named .gitconfig. On linux you will find the global config file here: **~/.gitconfig**, I suspect OSX being BSD derivative may be the same